# Is It possible to close the rest assured connection once the response generated using java

Tags: java, json, httprequest, httpresponse, rest-assured

I am using below code for passing JSON request to an API service.
It is working fine and getting request and response properly. Due to some server issues or network connection error , some times the opened connection is not closing automatically.
Is it possible to close the connection once the response created to avoid connection leakage. please advice.

**source code:**

```
io.restassured.response.Response 
    response
      = given()
          .auth()
            .none()
              .header("Content-Type","application/json")
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                  .when()
                    .body(requestJson)
                      .post(Endpoint);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use `HttpClient`  if its possible within your application.  With HttpClient you can set http timeout , set number of http connections via connection pooling.